# error C2039 about building tree , vs2010&win7 O.o

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, data-structures

### When learning data structures,I have written a code for building tree.After compile, it show error 2039 below: 'Left' : is not a member of 'TreeNode'.I have      no idea about how this error occur O.o

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MaxTree 10
#define ElementType char
#define Tree int
#define Null -1

struct TreeNode
{
    ElementType Element;  /*data*/
    Tree Left;            /*left child id*/
    Tree Right;           /*right cild id*/
}T1[MaxTree],T2[MaxTree];

...

Tree BuildTree(struct TreeNode T[])
{
int i;
int N;
int check[MaxTree];
char cl,cr;
int Root;

scanf("%d\n",&N); 
if(N){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){   
        check[i] = 0;   
        }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%c %c %c\n",&T[i].Element,&cl,&cr);
        if(cl!='-'){
            T[i].Left = cl-'0';   /*Report error C2039 !!!*/                     
            check[T[i].Left]=1;
        }
        else{
            T[i].Left = Null;    /*No report error C2039 !!!*/
        }

        if(cr!='-'){
            T[i].Right = cl-'0'; 
            check[T[i].Right]=1;
        }
        else{
            T[i].Right = Null
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)   
        if(!check[i]){
            break;
        }

    Root = i;

}

return Root; 
}

...
```

Comment: Please provide complete that reproduces the problem (no `...` please). See [mcve].

Comment: I can not reproduce such a problem. Also `T[i].Right = Null` --> `T[i].Right = Null;`

Comment: what happens when `N` is >= MaxTree.   Note by convention, names defined via a `#define` are ALL CAPS with an `-` underscore separating the root words

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  It is best, when preparing to call the function: `scanf()` to output a prompt to let the user know what they are expected to do.

Comment: regarding: `if(cr!='-'){
                T[i].Right = cl-'0';`  shouldn't the second line be: `T[i].Right = cr-'0';`  Note: `cr` not `cl`

Comment: after I corrected this statement: `T[i].Right = Null` by appending the missing `;`, it compiled with no problems.  BTW: how is the code supposed to know that `cl` and `cr` are a digit?  Perhaps you should insert a couple calls to `isdigit()` (found in ctype.h) to assure that fact before using the values.

Comment: Thanks~still think the reason